# crash when reading from a file

Tags: c++, arrays, file, crash

first of all, i'd like u to know that im a college student (our syllabus in programming is not that advanced yet)(Btw im not asking for answers to my assignments etc, im just practicing).

Ok so i have 2 problems

1. Some function in my code changes the value of my array (when i dont want it to)
2. I really have no idea, but it seems that getting some values from a file to store into my array crashes the program, furthermore, after fiddling a bit with the code (i have no idea what changed), it no longer crashes during the said part, BUT it still crashes at the end of the code execution..

i hope u guys could help me, i've been searching whole day long.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
void readFile (float x[], int &y) {
    ifstream load;
    string filename;
    cout << "Enter the name of the file: ";
    cin >> filename;

    load.open(filename.c_str());
    while (!load.eof()) {
        load >> x[y];
        y++;
    }
    if (!load) {
        cout << "asd";
    }

}

void computeC (float x[], int y, float z[]) {
    int v=0;

    for (v=0; v<=y; v++) {
        z[v] = (5 * (x[v] - 32)/9);
    }
}

float average (float x[], int y) {
    int v=0;
    float sum=0;
    for (v=0; v<=y; v++) {
        sum += x[v];
    }

    return sum / v;
}

void grade (float x[], char grades[], int y, int &hi, int &med, int &lo) {
    int v=0;
    hi = med = lo = 0;
    for (v=0; v<=y; v++) {
        if ( x[v] >= 35) {
        grades[v] = 'H';
        hi++;
        }

        else if ( (x[v] < 35) && (x[v] >= 20) ) {
        grades[v] = 'M';
        med++;
        }

        else if ( x[v] < 20 ) {
        grades[v] = 'L';    
        lo++;
        }
    }

}

void writeFile (float x[], float y[], int z, char w[]) {
    ofstream save;
    int v=0;


    for (v=0; v <= z; v++) {
        cout << "C(Celcius)" << left << setw(5);
        cout << "F(Farenheit)" << left << setw(5);
        cout << "Description\n";
        cout << right << setw(7) << y[v];
        cout << left << setw(8) << x[v];
        cout << left << setw(8) << w[v];        
    }
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int ctr=0, high, medium, low;
    float F[ctr], C[ctr], ave;
    char grades[ctr];


    readFile (F, ctr);
    computeC (F, ctr, C);
    ave = average (C, ctr);
    grade (C, grades, ctr, high, medium, low);

    cout << "Average of the temperatures: " << ave << endl;
    cout << "Number of high temperatures: " << high << endl;
    cout << "Number of medium temperatures: " << medium << endl;
    cout << "Number of low temperatures: " << low << endl;

    //writeFile (F, C, ctr, grades);


    return 0;
}
```

(Code from https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxeZTCUL3Q4oZHlqWFdjMDZub0E/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question could do with some improvement if you want to get help. Try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Tell us exactly what isn't working.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As for your problems, first of all don't do e.g. `while (!load.eof())` as it will not work as you expect it to. The `eofbit` flag will not be set until after you try to read from beyond the end of the file, so your loop will iterate one time to many. Secondly, in your `main` function you declare the arrays `F` and `C` to have *zero size*! This means that every access (read or write) to them will be out of bounds leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: You should also know that txtspk is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without checking the whole code I can directly think of some parts of the code.

Let me start with

```
while (!load.eof()) {
        load >> x[y];
        y++;
    }
```

Where you write more values than x[] can hold and your program will crash in that case.

Make sure to only write to your array up to the maximum allocated memory.

The problem is that !load.eof() will not do what you expect it to do as it will be read from beyond the end of the file. It will execute your loop one more time too much.

Second:

```
 int ctr=0, high, medium, low;
    float F[ctr], C[ctr], ave;
    char grades[ctr];
```

`ctr` is `0` so you declare Arrays of `F, c and grades` with 0 elements. That's not very clever ;) You can't read or write from them.

Comment: how do i fix this? i've tried not to initialize ctr to 0 (this makes the program to crash at startup). i need the program itself to determine the number of data to be stored into the array (and, in turn, the number becomes the size of the array) is there any way i can accomplish this?

Comment: yes in several ways. You can use a "container" like std::vector or allocate the memory dynamically at runtime using the "new" operator.